# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The region 'eu-west-2' is not a valid region

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying Spring boot application in the London region on an AWS beanstalk Platform but I am getting error:-

"**Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.region.StaticRegionProvider]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The region 'eu-west-2' is not a valid region!**"

I had even placed **cloud.aws.region.static=eu-west-2** and **cloud.aws.region.auto=false** in the ***application.properties file*** but still the error remains the same.

Please find the details error below:-

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.support.io.ResourceLoaderBeanPostProcessor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'amazonS3' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'amazonS3': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.region.RegionProvider.BEAN_NAME' while setting bean property 'regionProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'regionProvider': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.region.StaticRegionProvider]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The region 'eu-west-2' is not a valid region!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:171)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.pb.fusion.platform.export.services.Application.main(Application.java:35)



Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'amazonS3': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.region.RegionProvider.BEAN_NAME' while setting bean property 'regionProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'regionProvider': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.region.StaticRegionProvider]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The region 'eu-west-2' is not a valid region!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear that `eu-west-2` is a supported AWS region yet in Spring Cloud AWS.

`eu-west-1` does appear to be supported.

> Possible regions are (currently) us-east-1, us-west-1, us-west-2, eu-west-1, eu-central-1, ap-southeast-1, ap-southeast-1, ap-northeast-1, sa-east-1, cn-north-1 and any custom region configured with own region meta data

**Update**

Using Spring Boot 2.2.1.RELEASE and a modified version of the CloudFormation template [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/aws-refapp/blob/master/AwsSampleStack.template), I had no problem starting the webapp locally in the `eu-west-2` London AZ.  Can you verify the version of Spring Boot you're running?

**Reference:**

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.2.0.M2/reference/html/#_configuring_region

Comment: So is there a way through which I can overcome this error or example for creating custom region metadata.

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer above.  TL;DR: the latest version of Spring Cloud AWS supports `eu-west-2`.